# In Intl.RelativeTimeFormat what is the difference between narrow and short?

Tags: javascript

According to the documentation of [`Intl.RelativeTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/RelativeTimeFormat/RelativeTimeFormat) is says that the `options` parameter accepts `style` which has values long, short and narrow. I understand long and short, but what is narrow and how is it different from short?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript inherits its spec for date time formats from unicode locale data:  https://cldr.unicode.org/translation/date-time/date-time-names

The details of what exactly `narrow` or `short` might mean in any given language  are ... entirely language dependent. But in principle narrow seems to aim to be the shortest conceivable form even if not in common usage, and short seems to be the common short format.

I think the differences are mostly in textual representations:

```js
new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-GB", {month:'narrow'})
/// --> F
new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-GB", {month:'short'})
/// --> Feb
```

Answer (score 1):

It differs for a few locales otherwise none:

```js
function printRelativeTime(locale) {
  let rtf = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat(locale, {
    numeric: 'always',
    style: 'narrow'
  });
  console.log(locale, 'narrow: ', rtf.format(-1, 'day'));
  rtf = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat(locale, {
    numeric: 'always',
    style: 'short'
  });
  console.log(locale, 'short: ', rtf.format(-1, 'day'));
}

//['af', 'am', 'ar', 'arn', 'as', 'az', 'ba', 'be', 'bg', 'bn', 'bo', 'br', 'bs', 'ca', 'co', 'cs', 'cy', 'da', 'de', 'dsb', 'dv', 'el', 'en', 'es', 'et', 'eu', 'fa', 'fi', 'fil', 'fo', 'fr', 'fy', 'ga', 'gd', 'gl', 'gsw', 'gu', 'ha', 'he', 'hi', 'hr', 'hsb', 'hu', 'hy', 'id', 'ig', 'ii', 'in', 'is', 'it', 'iu', 'iw', 'ja', 'ka', 'kk', 'kl', 'km', 'kn', 'kok', 'ko', 'ky', 'lb', 'lo', 'lt', 'lv', 'mi', 'mk', 'ml', 'mn', 'moh', 'mr', 'ms', 'mt', 'nb', 'ne', 'nl', 'nn', 'no', 'nso', 'oc', 'or', 'pa', 'pl', 'prs', 'ps', 'pt', 'qut', 'quz', 'rm', 'ro', 'ru', 'rw', 'sah', 'sa', 'se', 'si', 'sk', 'sl', 'sma', 'smj', 'smn', 'sms', 'sq', 'sr', 'sv', 'sw', 'syr', 'ta', 'te', 'tg', 'th', 'tk', 'tlh', 'tn', 'tr', 'tt', 'tzm', 'ug', 'uk', 'ur', 'uz', 'vi', 'wo', 'xh', 'yo', 'zh', 'zu'].forEach(a => printRelativeTime(a));
printRelativeTime('sv');
printRelativeTime('fr');
printRelativeTime('en');
```